# PHP echo before sleep function, not working

Tags: php, sleep

I want output echo in browser (every time) before sleep function execute.

following code is not working

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush(1);
    ob_start();
    echo "Start<Br>";
    ob_flush();

    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $randSlp=rand(1,3);
        //echo str_repeat(" ", 1024);
        echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. ";
        ob_flush();

        sleep($randSlp);
    }
    ob_end_flush();
```

if uncomment `str_repeat` function than in browser 
First time :
Start
Sleeping for 1 second.
Sleeping for 3 second.

Second time : Sleeping for 2 second.
Sleeping for 2 second.

and continue...

is possible echo one by one without str_repeat() function, why output doesn't display every time.

Comment: You may need to flush your output buffer. `ob_flush()`?

Comment: @J.D.Pace I am using  `ob_flush();` after echo, or need to put other  place

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following code and its work.

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(1);
//apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
//ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
//ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $randSlp=rand(1,3);
    echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. ";;
    sleep(1);
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
       ob_end_flush(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Answer (score 2):

even the output buffer (ob_* functions) do not necessarily give output to browser directly.

First try calling `flush()` before or after `ob_flush()`.

Second, look if mod_gzip or zlib.output_compression is turned on for example. This will also buffer all output.

If using IIS server and not Apache, there might also be settings in IIS to check.

Comment: I tried `flush()` before and after `ob_flush()` its not work.

Comment: @RSSisodiya Ok, so as I said, chkeck mod_gzip and zlib.output_compression. Do `phpinfo()` and check if _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] does gzip and check if zlib.output_compression is turned on. These will block direct outputting

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]`. return gzip, deflate.

Comment: and i have set `ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "On");` (in my php file) but still not working

Comment: @RSSisodiya Try turning it OFF :). To compress involves buffering everything first before being able to compress it.

Comment: so how about mod_gzip? ... what is your _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] setting in `phpinfo()` ? (And what web server are you using? Apache?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28741/discussion-between-rs-sisodiya-and-nl-x)

Comment: no idea about mod_gzip. I am using Apache Xampp. I have try echo $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]; its return gzip, deflate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here looking for why the code :

```php
echo "start...";
sleep(5);
echo "end";
```

does not output first `echo` right after calling it, then the answer is you need to turn off output buffering. You can do it by calling [ob_end_flush();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) or [ob_end_clean();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

So the following code will output `start...";` right after first `echo` has been called:

```
ob_end_clean();
echo "start...";
sleep(5);
echo "end";
```

You should understand how `ob_end_clean()` and `ob_end_flush()` works because it make actions such erasing output or sending it if it was inititated before.