# sleep function does not work as expected inside loop

Tags: php

I have the following configuration:
1) Zend Server 6.0.1 with Apache 2.2.22
2) Windows Server 2003

I'm simply running this small script:

```
<?
set_time_limit(0);
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
echo 'test'.'<br>';
sleep(60);
}
?>
```

the output is ONLY 1 test.

this drove me crazy, could anybody help me with this ?

p.s. i've tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170028/php-echo-before-sleep-function-in-for-loop-not-working), but it also didn't work as expected, it echoes 2 tests only.

Comment: first things first: is php running in safe mode? if yes, the call to set_time_limit() is a noop and you may hit the execution time limit.

Comment: `sleep(60)` indicates 1 minute sleep

Comment: As a note - always uses `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: @Mario: how to know if it runs in  safe mode or not ? one Trick Pony: yes

Comment: If there is no output buffering being dealt with, this output will be shown all together and not in a sequence

Comment: @marioP: php is not under safe mode using if( ini_get('safe_mode') )

Comment: are there any errors? try placing `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the script.

Comment: no errors displayed with E_ALL

Comment: what http server are you using (if any)? Maybe the timeout happens there?

Comment: This worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170028/php-echo-before-sleep-function-not-working

Answer (score 1):

From PHP manual:
When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Try placing `set_time_limit(0);` into the loop itself.

Comment: This is so not helpful. Also, why should this be called repeatedly? Unlimited execution time is unlimited, no matter how often you call it.

Comment: I agree, but if for some reason max execution time cannot be overridden, it will at least reset it every time.

Comment: i've tried this solution and it didn't work, it displayed 2 'tests' instead of 5

Comment: @JAHelia it must be running in safe mode then, from PHP manual again: This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini. Here's how to switch it off: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/119/turning-off-php-safe-mode-on-your-server

Comment: my PHP is not running under safe mode, how do i know? with this : if( ini_get('safe_mode') )

Comment: phpinfo() should tell you if it's in safe mode.

Comment: @JAHelia Just give it a try to add ini_set('safe_mode', 'Off'); in the beginning and see what happens.

Comment: @VigintasLabakojis: there is no entry in phpinfo() that tells me that

Comment: @VigintasLabakojis same error with ini_set('safe_mode', 'Off');

Comment: @JAHelia check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094839/php-set-time-limit-does-not-work-safemode-is-off Maybe it's set in your apache conf and cannot be overridden by the script?

Comment: @VigintasLabakojis regarding your linked answer: the time limit in php.ini is 1000 (actually i have set it to 1000)