# php issue with while and sleep , the while loop echo all only at the end of the loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sleep

I have a php issue with while and sleep , the while loop echo all only at the end of the loop insted of echo every 1 second

I've tried this:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();


$i=0;
while($i<=5) {
     echo $i;
     sleep(1);
     flush();
     $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I just ran that code and it added a single number to the list every second. So did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: It`s loading the page 5 seconds and echo all the five number at once

Comment: @bill But if you run in CLI you will see each number of other.

Comment: what is CLI I googled it but didn`t find nothing

Comment: CLI means using the command console to run PHP scripts instead of running them as a page in a webserver

Comment: Command Line Interface. From bash, or cmd...

Comment: okay I understand but how I can fix it? mybe It`s not depends of the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It working at my browser

```
<?php
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','Off');// if not in php.ini
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
$i=0;
while($i<=5) {
     echo $i;
     flush();
     sleep(1);
     $i++;
}
?>
```

Ensure this value in php.ini `zlib.output_compression=Off`

Also refer all the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170028/php-echo-before-sleep-function-not-working) for detailed answer

Comment: Have you restart your apache server if changed that above value in php.ini. I checked in my end its display each number for each second

Comment: I putted the value in php.ini file that in the same folder mybe I need to change the permissions of the page if yes what permission number should it be?

Comment: Try to edit the file in root privilege using terminal. Dont change its permission it might lead to some other problem.

Comment: Don't add it zlib.output_compression as a new entry. Search inside php.ini if its already there update its value to Off, otherwise add it as new

Comment: Then how will you run php man . If you don't know how to do means, better restart your machine

Comment: I use free hosting that support of php sql ftp and etc so it`s okay I guess

Comment: ok.If so, I edited this php.ini value in program itself. Copy the code in the answer and try once again in your browser

Comment: can`t see what you changed it`s still the same zlib.output_compression=Off

Comment: very first line is last added one. you take the code overall and try

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!ob_get_level()) {
    ob_start();
} else {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
}

$i = 0;
while ($i <= 5) {
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    echo $i . "\n";
    $i++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

This code will begin with flushing all your echo's and will then start outputting echo's one by one.